# How to display images from oracle database into image control

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application i need to show the image of the logged in user which is saved in Oracle database as LONG RAW data type.can anybody guide me how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Its No Depend On Your DataBase(Oracel,SqlServer,....)They are all the same Way
Please Say You Save Data With binary Or Varchar 
if You Save With Binary First Must Be Convert To string And in

If Have Any Question Please Replay
im Surry if My Help Not Good

Comment: I checked data type of field in my table, and it is showing LONG RAW. The content of the field are mix of characters and numbers and It has very long data which i can not put here because of restriction of length

Comment: How can i convert it to string?

Comment: Hi,anybody can help. I did some work around for the issue.

Comment: Hi,I am selecting the image content from the database with select statement and saving it in a variable defined as byte and in my view i am using image control with this code <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,Session("UserImage")' /> but nothing is showing. Kindly help me for this